# Does the bit generated password using QKD protocols need to be converted to another base?

Tags: cryptography, qkd

I am currently implementing some QKD protocols using Qiskit and I came up with the following question: After the protocol is finished, a true random password is generated using 0s and 1s, however, and here my question, do these passwords need to be converted to another base? Maybe hexadecimal? Or are they used as they are?

When I mean by used is to using them, for instance, as a key for the one time pad.

Comment: My guess is that it depends on the security protocol you are going to be using. If the one time pad requires a hexadecimal number, then just convert your already random password to hexadecimal. The same with deciaml or other bases.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Do you happen to know if the one time pad uses a bit type string or alphanumeric? or maybe hexadecimal?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography_with_python/cryptography_with_python_one_time_pad_cipher.htm) very simple example. Here a key made up of letters is used. However, if you want to send more complex messages (e.g. files), you could use a numerical key that serves a similar purpose. I'm not very experienced in this topic, but this is my guess.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs to the Cryptography StackExchange site, since Quantum Computing isn't involved anymore once the QKD is done.